# How to simulate pressing buttons to keep on scraping more elements with Scrapy

Tags: scrapy

On this page (https://www.realestate.com.kh/buy/), I managed to grab a list of ads, and individually parse their content with this code:

```
import scrapy

class scrapingThings(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scrapingThings'
    # allowed_domains = ['https://www.realestate.com.kh/buy/']
    start_urls = ['https://www.realestate.com.kh/buy/']

    def parse(self, response):
        ads = response.xpath('//*[@class="featured css-ineky e1jqslr40"]//a/@href')
        c = 0
        for url in ads:
            c += 1
            absolute_url = response.urljoin(url.extract())
            self.item = {}
            self.item['url'] = absolute_url

            yield scrapy.Request(absolute_url, callback=self.parse_ad, meta={'item': self.item})

    def parse_ad(self, response):

        # Extract things

        yield {
            # Yield things
        }
```

However, I'd like to automate the switching from one page to another to grab the entirety of the ads available (not only on the first page, but on all pages). By, I guess, simulating the pressings of the 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 50 buttons as displayed on this screen capture:

[image]

Is this even possible with Scrapy? If so, how can one achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Let me show you two ways of doing it:

You can have your spider select the buttons, get the `@href` value of them, build a [full] URL and `yield` as a new request.
Here is an example:

```py
def parse(self, response):
    ....
    href = response.xpath('//div[@class="desktop-buttons"]/a[@class="css-owq2hj"]/following-sibling::a[1]/@href').get()
    req_url = response.urljoin(href)
    yield Request(url=req_url, callback=self.parse_ad)
```

- The selector in the example will always return the `@href` of the next page's button (*It returns only one value, if you are in page 2 it returns the `@href` of page 2*)
- In this page, the href is an relative url, so we need to use `response.urljoin()` method to build a full url. It will use the response as base.
- We `yield` a new request, the response will be parsed in the callback function you determined.
- This will require your callback function to always yield the request for the next page. So it's a recursive solution.

A more simple approach would be to just observe the pattern of the hrefs and manually `yield` all requests. Each button has a href of `"/buy/?page={nr}"` where `{nr}` is the number of the page, se can arbitrarily change this nr value and yield all requests at once.

```py
def parse(self, response):
    ....
    nr_pages = response.xpath('//div[@class="desktop-buttons"]/a[@class="css-1en2dru"]//text()').getall()
    last_page_nr = int(nr_pages[-1])
    for nr in range(2, last_page_nr + 1):
        req_url = f'/buy/?page={nr}'
        yield Request(url=response.urljoin(req_url), callback=self.parse_ad)
```

- `nr_pages` returns the number of all buttons
- `last_page_nr` selects the last number (*which is the last available page*)
- We loop in the range between 2 to the value of `last_page_nr` (*50 in this case*) and in each loop we request a new page (that correspond to the number).
- This way you can make all the requests in your `parse` method, and parse the response in the `parse_ad` without recursive calling.

---

Finally I suggest you take a look on [scrapy tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) it covers several common scenarios on scraping.

Comment: The second solution seems intuitive, which is great (for me). However, I'm not sure how to iterate through all ads found on each page (for url in ads:)?

Comment: @LucienS. glad to hear. I won't edit my answer because this seems unrelated to the original question, as we are now talking of ads and not of the page's buttons. The logic is you should find a selector that selects only the ads (individually) and you iterate over the items on this SelectorList, like `for ad in response.xpath('//div[@class="css-1t6g48l eq4or9x0"]'):`. For each iteration you extract the data you want from the ad: `title = ad.xpath('header/a/text()').get()`